# CSS анимация зацикливание

Tags: jquery, css, css3, css-animation

есть анимация

```
@keyframes sprite-x {
  0% { background-position-x: 0; }
  100% { background-position-x: -8192px;}
 }


 .element {
  width: 1638px;
  height: 473px;
  background-image: url('image');
  background-repeat: none;
  animation:
    sprite-x 0.5s steps(6) infinite,

 }
```

Нужно чтобы примерно на 90% этой анимации запустилась заново она, но первая при этом не прерывается, а доигрывается до конца, а потом прекращается.
И так бесконечно:  на 90% запускается одна и та же анимация без останова предыдущей, пока последняя не доиграет до конца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Горизонтальная шкала это время анимации

Answer (score 2):

В свойстве [animation-delay](http://htmlbook.ru/css/animation-delay) укажи два значения через запятую. Возможно, придётся изменить анимации таким образом, чтобы они имели равную длительность.

Comment: так анимация одна и таже - соотвественно длительность одинаковая

Comment: @ruslik, видимо я чего-то не понимаю и следует уточнить вопрос...

Comment: всегда проигрывается одна и та же анимация, только на 90% первого проигрывания запускается анимация второй раз, но первая при этом не прекращается а доигрывает до конца и так в цикле

Comment: Если запустить ещё раз ту же анимацию, то анимироваться должны будут те же свойства. Как ты хочешь одновременно анимировать одни и те же свойства? И в вопросе я вижу две анимации.

Comment: то есть нужны 2 блока с анимацией и показывать поочередно

Comment: Имелось ввиду что это одна анимация , которая состоит из 2 поданимация. Так вот эта общая анимация и должна запускаться все время с интервалом в 10%

Comment: @ruslik, чем конкретно не подходит мой ответ?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @ruslik, делаешь одну анимацию на 180% длительности и используешь animation-delay. Вроде всё в соответствии с ответом?

Comment: у меня всего одна анимация(по стилям имеется ввиду, то есть анимаций 2 но они одинаковые), но на разных блоках
Что значит 180% длительности
Анимация запускается на первом блоке, как только она достигает уровня в 90% включается другая(но по стилям такая же) анимация на втором блоке, при этом анимация на первом блоке доигрывает и прекращается. а на втором играет и как только 90%, опять вклчается анимация на первом блоке, вторая доигрывает и прекращается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44724/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ruslik).